# "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'"

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get a list of venues to display, and then count the number of upcoming shows.  I'm running into the error at `filtered_upcomingshows = [show for show in upcomingshows if show.start_time > current_time]`.  The model has the `start_time` field set to DateTime, and `current_time` is set as DateTime (unless I'm misunderstanding how it's used?).  I can't figure out which one is being read as a string.  How would I fix this?

```
    class Show(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'shows'

      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artists.id'), nullable = False)
      venue_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('venues.id'), nullable = False)
      start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False)
    
      def __repr__(self):
        return '<Show {} {}>'.format(self.artist_id, self.venue_id)
   


    @app.route('/venues')
    def venues():
    
      current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M')
      venue_city_state = ''
    
      data = []
      # queries Venue db for all records
      venues = Venue.query.all()
    
      for venue in venues:
        upcomingshows = venue.shows
    
        filtered_upcomingshows = [show for show in upcomingshows if show.start_time > current_time]
    
        if venue_city_state == venue.city + venue.state:
          data[len(data) - 1]["venues"].append({
            "id": venue.id, 
            "name": venue.name,
            "num_upcoming_shows": len(filtered_upcomingshows)
          })
        else:
          venue_city_state == venue.city + venue.state
          data.append({
            "city": venue.city, 
            "state": venue.state, 
            "venues": [{
              "id": venue.id, 
              "name": venue.name, 
              "num_upcoming_shows": len(filtered_upcomingshows)
            }]
          })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is (as the interpreter says) that `current_time` is a string and `show.start_time` is a `datetime.datetime` instance. To solve this issue you can just drop the `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M')` call when defining `current_time`.

> `date.strftime(format)`
>
> Return a string representing the date, controlled by an explicit format string. Format codes referring to hours, minutes or seconds will see 0 values. For a complete list of formatting directives, see `strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Comment: Ah, I was referencing another bit of code and made the assumption that all of that was necessary to format it or something.  Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M')
```

.strftime is documented to [return a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), just nix the call and it will work:

```
current_time = datetime.now()
```